# iPod can't work as development device after reset

Tags: ios, device, reset

my iPod works well as an development device.

But after I reset the iPod, my XCode doesnot recognize it any longer.

Its color turns yellow in organizer of XCode, instead of green dot before.

Please help. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my question closed.

When I open Xcode 4.3, it can recognize my iPod as before.

Then I switch back to my Xcode 3.2.6, my iPod turn green again.

So strange. It works anyway. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "reset" you mean you restored the iPod, then all of your provisioning profiles, etc. will have been deleted from the device preventing Xcode from building to the device. To fix this, select the device in the Xcode organizer (where the yellow dot is) and click the button that says something to the effect of "Use for development".

At this point Xcode will prompt you for your developer credentials, check DDI symbols (and all that other fun stuff), and install the necessary profiles to the device.

Comment: thanks! I did not find the button that says something to the effect of "Use for development". then I right-clicked my iPod ( that with yellow dot ) and select " Add to Provisioning Portal", then it keeps asking me to input : " iPhone Provisioning Portal login " 's user name and password. I input them but Xcode keeps ask me. why?

Comment: @user1188849 The only reasons I can think of that Xcode would do this are if you are entering invalid credentials or there aren't any valid certs/profiles for those credentials.

Comment: I do enter valid credentials and there are valid certs/profiles for those credentials.iOS installed on my iPod is " 5.1.1 (9B206)". "Xcode can't find the software image to install this version." There are prompt in the summary as follows:"The version of iOS on ““Sunlight”的 iPod” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.".  thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is probably missing your development profiles, make sure you reinstall them in organizer prior to attempting to use them for development

Comment: thanks! I download the Team provision profile again, and drag it into my organizer, but still failed to enable my iPod as development device.